# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/params/SyncBasicHttpParams

Tags: jakarta-ee, osgi, integration-testing, maven-3

hi guys
I am trying to run integration test on an OSGI based web app
when I tried that I get the error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/params/SyncBasicHttpParams

any ideas how to solve that ?

Comment: Run maven with stacktrace enabled. This will give you info on what could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that your bundle imports the package `org.apache.http.params`, e.g.:

```
Import-Package: org.apache.http.params
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look here for what to do when you encounter NoClassDefFoundError:

http://jroller.com/sjivan/entry/difference_between_classnotfoundexception_and_noclassdeffounderror

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the bundle that contains the class org/apache/http/params/SyncBasicHttpParams ACTIVE in your platform.

Comment: Incorrect. Bundle activation has nothing to do with class resolution.

Comment: Right, I answered without thinking too much.